# GET request failing with a valid access Token

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers, access-token

I have an account on the website: https://dev.yuride.network/
I am using it for testing purposes. There is a particular API that I am getting issues with
https://dev.yuride.network/api/users/me/
I am making GET request to the above URL and passing the access token like:
`response = requests.get(url, headers={'accesstoken': accessToken})`
The access token is obtained by making an API call to
https://dev.yuride.network/api/token/?name=xyz and passing payload data with
`username` and `password` this API is successfully returning the access token with JSON

```
{
"access":"asdsad",
"refresh":"asdasd"
}
```

But the request `requests.get(URL, headers={'accesstoken': accessToken})` is failing
I am not sure if I am passing the header the wrong way or the key to be used should be
different than the `accesstoken` that I am using

I copied the curl command from the inspect tab while going to /api/user/me from the address bar :

```
curl 'https://dev.yuride.network/api/users/me/' \
  -H 'authority: dev.yuride.network' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/99.0.1150.55' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: saml_session=aayrv7sksot1ooztihpht7svi5cydcet; csrftoken=6sQYPXR7ldqU5LCuR19DkUvsRbWmyll4TamiM4DqjKQdzWTh4u3TGkvI8ZwgGYbp; sessionid=5r6v6uk5vv3aufyt82np2guxn30pa3gu' \
  --compressed
```

The above command runs fine on bash shell. It doesn't have any access token

Comment: Providing **Reproducible** code snippets will make it easier for us to help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you sure that `accesstoken` is the right header key? I strongly believe that `access_token` or `accessToken` are far more common.

Comment: Have you tried `headers={"Access-Token": accessToken}`?

Comment: @Malsesto I tried access_token and accessToken none of them worked. I am not sure if accesstoken is the right header key. I have access to the website. So if I log in there I am able to navigate to api/users/me page. I checked the request headers in chrome inspect but there was no access token instead a `cookie` with `csrftoken` and `sessionid`

Comment: @HaiVu I tried it. Didn't work. The website doesn't mention the exact header. But since the API /api/token returns the access and refresh tokens there could be a way to access the API /api/users/me programmatically

Comment: @chintu You can try to connect to the api with [postman](https://postman.com) first. There you have a nice GUI and tons of possibilities to explore APIs and how to connect to them and once you get your desired result you can simply copy-paste python code.
And maybe explore your docs :)

Comment: @Malsesto, I will try postman. But what could be making the GET call from chrome work? I am pasting a screenshot of it

Comment: What if you change it to a POST-call? Because you say that you pass username and password as payload which implies that you have to use POST. 
Passing payload in GET is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: Have you tried
`headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {your_token}'}` ?